# How to select one specific element with a class when this element is repeated on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a WordPress Site with ACF Pro. One of the Blocks I created is an image with a play button overlay. When the user clicks on the overlay div, a module pops up with an embedded YouTube video that plays automatically and also stop playing when pressing on an external close button.

I do have the html, css and jQuery code for this. However, my issue is now that this ACF Block will sometimes appear multiple times on one page but since the code is then always the same, the click on the play button (or overlay) will always trigger to play the very first embedded YouTube video but not the other ones.

Is there a way I can rewrite my jQuery to select only the specific element that has been triggered even though the same element exist above in the page as well with the same code?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-w-id="d0f29131-3fc1-c17d-1d06-cac855c814b2" class="behandlung_details_rechts" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_field( 'bild_video_bild' ); ?>');">
      <a data-w-id="c77b6487-4cbc-7de8-8415-fa31986a0544" href="#" class="behandlung_details_overlay play-video w-inline-block">
        <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/play.png') ?>); -webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0);transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0) skew(0, 0)" class="play_button"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;opacity:0" class="video_popup_wrapper">
      <div class="video_div">
        <div class="html-embed w-embed w-iframe"><iframe class="youtube-video" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/<?php the_field('bild_video_video_id'); ?>?enablejsapi=1" modestbranding="0" controls="0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="">
          </iframe></div>
      </div>
      <a data-w-id="ccf28eaf-2e0e-5002-536f-6d47e7efb6d7" href="#" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/close.png') ?>);" class="stop-video w-inline-block"></a>
    </div>
```

Any my jQuery:

```
$('.play-video').click(function(){
$('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'playVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});


$('a.stop-video').click(function(){
  $('.youtube-video')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
});
```

Comment: your <a> tags have a data-w-id, i think you should use them.
`$('.play-video').click(function(){ let wID = $(this).data('w-id');}`

Comment: @toffler thanks, I tried this but it doesn't work. The video doesn't start playing anymore with this when you click on the overlay